# Send parameters from controller to model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, controller

I'm working on the Meetup Api.
I would like to save some conferences from the API into my database.
The saving conferences depend of the parameters passing into the view to the controller :

```
  <%= link_to 'See conferences', conferences_path(:title => "ParisRb")%> |
```

Then I call the good method to look for the good conferences (comparing to the params) among all the one received from the api.
I would like the methods to be very generic and to be able to save any conferences not only 'ParisRb'.

So I modify all my methods in this goal but there is one I can not modify, I don't know how.

This is my whole code. The one I'd like to modify is `self.conferences_filter(data)` wich is supposed to receive the params from the controller instead of 'ParisRb'. But I know that passing parameters from the controller to the model is not a good practice. So any idea is welcome :)

**lib/api_meetup.rb**

```
class ApiMeetup
  BASE_URI = "https://api.meetup.com"

  def events(urlname)
    HTTParty.get(BASE_URI + "/#{urlname}/events")
  end
end
```

**conferences_controller.rb**

```
def index
    #call to the API
    response = ApiMeetup.new.events(params[:title])
    api_data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    filtered_conferences = Conference.conferences_filter(api_data)
    conferences = Conference.save_conferences_from_api(filtered_conferences)

    @conferences = conferences.current_conferences
  end
```

**conference.rb**

```
#Keep only requested conferences
  def self.conferences_filter(data)
    requested_conferences = []
    data.each do |event|
      if event["name"].include?('ParisRb') #This should receive params[:title] instead of 'ParisRb'
        requested_conferences << event
      end
    end
    requested_conferences
  end

  #Save requested conferences from the Meetup API
  def self.save_conferences_from_api(conferences)
    # data = data_from_api
    conferences.each do |line|
      conference = self.new
      conference.title = line['name']
      conference.date = format_date(line['time'])
      conference.url = line['link']
      if conference.valid?
        conference.save
      end
    end
   self.all
  end
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. since you already querying `HTTParty.get(BASE_URI + "/#{urlname}/events")`, the returned events only limited to `urlname` which is `ParisRb`, it wouldn't include any other meetup groups' events. so there's no need to check again in the model. Unless you want to check the name of the event, which is what you are doing in the model methods.

Comment: Oh yes you are completely right ! There is one useless step in my code

Answer (score 0):

That's was actually quite obvious.
I just needed to pass to argument to my method :

`filtered_conferences = Conference.conferences_filter(api_data, params[:title])`

```
#Keep only requested conferences
  def self.conferences_filter(data, title)
    requested_conferences = []
    data.each do |event|
      if event["name"].include?(title)
        requested_conferences << event
      end
    end
    requested_conferences
  end
```